# How to display stacked bars in combination with normal bar in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, bar-chart, stacked

I have three values, two of which should be combined to a stacked bar, and the third just as a normal one. How would that work in Highcharts? I read the data from a CSV file.

[Here is the link](http://geodev.grid.unep.ch/megatrends/data/bafu/waldflaeche_ch.php?lang=de) to the existing graph. The "Nutzung" and "Absterberate" should be combined, the "Zuwachs" should be a single bar.

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set in plotOptions `stacked: 'normal'` and then for each series you can define `stack` see: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.stack

Comment: This looks great. Thanks. However, the data must then be coded directly into the javascript and not come from a CSV file, right?

Comment: Ok, hardcoded it into the javascript and works correctly. Thanks.

Comment: You can use csv from external file, take look at examples here: http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocesssing-data-from-a-file